# Adding PPA repository to Ubuntu LTS 22.04 seems to break https method of apt

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, ppa, https

I've already asked on the repository of ppa:ondrej/php on [github](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1833), but they didn't provide support, so I'm guessing it has to do with ubuntu. I couldn't find anything about this online.

I'm trying to install php 5.6 on a fresh (and updated) instance of Ubuntu LTS 22.04 server with apache2. When I'm adding the ppa repository with `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` I get the following output:

```
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php.gpg with fingerprint 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
```

After this all operations on apt seem to be broken:

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
```

To return to normal operating conditions I have to to execute `add-apt-repository  -r  ppa:ondrej/php`

Note that I tried `ppa:ondrej/apache2`  too, but with the same results. All commands are executed with root privileges.

Am I missing something here? I've tried the same exact installation but on Ubuntu LTS 20.04 and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't see any general error. After removing the PPA again, you can run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Does it work correctly? Then please check if you have some other PPA, or other 'special' package installed that might cause a conflict? - I develop and maintain `ppa:mkusb/ppa`. Can you install that PPA? (Just for checking if it works; you can remove it afterwards.)

Comment: Yes, if I remove the PPA I can execute without errors `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`, but I got nothing to update. I do not have any other ppa or package installed other then apache2, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is in fact empty.

Comment: I tried to add your ppa, but I got the same error: ```#  add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
[...]
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mkusb-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mkusb-ubuntu-ppa.gpg with fingerprint 29D76ADA2D15A87BF4C68B823729827454B8C8AC
[...Omitted Hits of http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.```

Comment: Then I would say that there is something wrong with your apt system (or the system behind it). We cannot blame `ppa:ondrej/php`. Is your 22.04 system installed from scratch or upgraded from an earlier version? What would happen if you remove also the package apache2? - If nothing else helps, you can backup your personal files and re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: As the Developer has [mentioned](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1833#issuecomment-1247125775) "This is unrelated to this repository. Your system is broken". Please upgrade your apt and apt-transport-https

Comment: I have upgraded and updated apt and reinstalled apt-transport-https. The problem still persists. I want to stress out that this a new installation on the system made very recently. Again. I've just executed an `apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and installed apache2 and nothing else. I've installed the system from the [official](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/) server iso and updated the installer during the installation process. This is a virtual machine running on esxi 7 but I don't think it's the source of the issue, since again, on ubuntu lts 20.04 everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you need to override node html with GnuTLS in ESXi, Please add this line in `.bashrc` :

```
export GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1
```

For Long-Term use. Finally run Update and Upgrade your system.

References :

- https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/ItKoVDieSow?pli=1
- https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Debugging-and-auditing.html

Comment: Yes that was it. I did append to `.bashrc` the line `export GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1` and rebooted the system. Afterwards I run a  `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and now I can add PPAs without issues. Thanks.

Comment: @Anckermann Well done! You are Welcome. you can click check Up-Vote for good question and good answer.

Comment: +1; Thanks for a good answer :-)